# Grant admin access to user UAC

Tags: authentication, uac

All my pc's are windows 10 pro. All the users that use the pc have standard user access. And I have administrator access.

There is times like today where the end user needs admin rights to  install an application or driver's or run an application update ect....

So I go to there pc and type in my password and move on. No big deal.

My question is, is there a way use a flashdrive or a usb key to give access to the user without having to type anything?  (See image below for example where I'm typing in the password)

I looked into yubikey but it seems as though it's for 2 factor authentication and singing into windows.
Will this double for what I'm trying to do?

I dont mind installing 3rd party software if need be to https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kOCc.png

Comment: Any process is automatically launched with the lowest permission possible.  Since you are using Windows 10 you are not going to avoid the UAC without disabling it entirely.

Comment: @ramhound I dont mind having it. In fact I want it I just want to use a key/flashdrive to populate the password  automatically

Comment: What you describe does not exist.

Comment: You can simply use a program like FreeCommander/cmd.exe ... and create a link that starts it using runas with saved admin credentials. Then this program can be used to start any other program with admin permissions. Note that often installer won't work properly when started using runas.